# Pivot Tables on python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a csv with a table of data. I would like to read the csv and write a new xlsx file based on the initial csv.

However, I would also like to add a new column that will have a value based on the name of the header (e.g if the header contains the word online) and create sort of a pivot table based on this logic. So as opposed to having three columns for leads, I would have one column represented by three rows (for each column)

```
date    online_won    retail_won     outbound_won    online_leads   retail_leads     outbound_leads
1/1/11     9            10              11             12             14
2/1/11     1            2               13             15
3/1/11     10           8               14             17
```

This is the desired output

```
date      source   won    leads
1/1/11    online    9       12
1/1/11    retail   10       14
1/1/11    outbound 11       
.....
```

I would assume that I can solve this using pd.pivot_table. But can't figure out how to return columns as won and leads and extract only the online/retail/outbound part from the existing columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), with a little extra work on the columns, since wide format variables are assumed to start with the stub names:

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(j for j in i[::-1]) for i in df.columns.str.split('_')]
(pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['won','leads'], i='date', j='source', suffix='_\w+')
   .reset_index())

    date     source   won  leads
0  1/1/11    _online    9   12.0
1  2/1/11    _online    1   15.0
2  3/1/11    _online   10   17.0
3  1/1/11    _retail   10   14.0
4  2/1/11    _retail    2    NaN
5  3/1/11    _retail    8    NaN
6  1/1/11  _outbound   11    NaN
7  2/1/11  _outbound   13    NaN
8  3/1/11  _outbound   14    NaN
```

Comment: This is exactly my solution :-).

Comment: Ha! seems like we had the same thought process there :) @quang

Answer (score 2):

With a column rename, you can use `wide_to_long`

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(x.split('_')[::-1]) for x in df.columns ]
pd.wide_to_long(df, ['won','leads'], 'date', 'source', sep='_', suffix='\w+')
```

Output:

```
                 won  leads
date   source              
1/1/11 online      9   12.0
2/1/11 online      1   15.0
3/1/11 online     10   17.0
1/1/11 retail     10   14.0
2/1/11 retail      2    NaN
3/1/11 retail      8    NaN
1/1/11 outbound   11    NaN
2/1/11 outbound   13    NaN
3/1/11 outbound   14    NaN
```

Comment: nice one.. better than mine for this usecase

Answer (score 2):

Another way using [`melt`](https://www.google.com/search?q=df+melt&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=df+melt&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4j69i60.1201j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [`series.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)`:

```
m=df.melt('date').sort_values('date')
m[['Source','Status']]=m.pop('variable').str.split('_',expand=True)
final=(m.set_index(['date','Source','Status']).unstack()
             .droplevel(0,axis=1).reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1))
```

---

```
     date    Source  leads   won
0  1/1/11    online   12.0   9.0
1  1/1/11  outbound    NaN  11.0
2  1/1/11    retail   14.0  10.0
3  2/1/11    online   15.0   1.0
4  2/1/11  outbound    NaN  13.0
5  2/1/11    retail    NaN   2.0
6  3/1/11    online   17.0  10.0
7  3/1/11  outbound    NaN  14.0
8  3/1/11    retail    NaN   8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `MultiIndex`, so possible [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) by first level `0`:

```
df = df.set_index('date')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack(0).rename_axis(('date','Source')).reset_index()
print (df)
     date    Source  leads  won
0  1/1/11    online   12.0    9
1  1/1/11  outbound    NaN   11
2  1/1/11    retail   14.0   10
3  2/1/11    online   15.0    1
4  2/1/11  outbound    NaN   13
5  2/1/11    retail    NaN    2
6  3/1/11    online   17.0   10
7  3/1/11  outbound    NaN   14
8  3/1/11    retail    NaN    8
```